# Weyl character formula in Sagemath

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, math-software, sagemath

I asked a question on AskSageMath: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/60597/weyl-character-formula-in-sagemath/

But no one answers. So I ask the question here.

I am trying to program Weyl character formula in Sage as follows:

```
A2 = WeylCharacterRing("A2")
a2 = WeightRing(A2)
L = A2.space()
W = L.weyl_group()
Lambda = L.simple_roots()[1]+L.simple_roots()[2]
rho = L.rho().coerce_to_sl()
r1 = sum((-1)^(w.length())*a2(w.action(Lambda+rho)) for w in W)
r2 = prod(1-a2(-alpha) for alpha in L.positive_roots())
r3 = a2(-rho)
```

Now I want to compute r1*r3/r2. But there is some error: AttributeError: 'WeightRing_with_category.element_class' object has no attribute 'quo_rem'

How to fix this problem?

Also the result of r2 is:

```
a2(0,0,0) + a2(-2,1,1) - a2(-2,0,2) + a2(-1,-1,2) - a2(-1,1,0) - a2(0,-1,1)
```

How to translate r2 (and the final result of Weyl character) into a form which is easier to read? I would like to write it as a Laurent polynomial in $e^{\omega_1}, e^{\omega_2}$, where $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are fundamental weights.

Thank you very much.

Comment: IDK, but that error sounds like it has to do with "quo"tients and "rem"ainders. I'm sure sagemath can handle power series to some degree, so rewrite r2$^{-1}$ as a product of power series and multiply r1*r3*r2$^{-1}$.

Comment: I think you can use `WeylCharacterRing("A2", style="coroots")` which will represent the weight space as $\mathbb{Z}^2$ rather than the sums-to-zero subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: @Joppy, thank you very much for your suggestions! Using WeylCharacterRing("A2", style="coroots"), the result is easier to read.

Comment: @DavidHill, thank you very much! Do you know how to rewrite $r_2^{-1}$ as a  power series using sage?

Comment: Well, $(1-a2(-alpha))^{-1}=1+a2(-alpha)+a2(-alpha)^2+\cdots=1+a2(-alpha)+a2(-2*alpha)+\cdots$, right? I would try $$\mathrm{sum}(a2(-k*alpha),0,\mathrm{infinity})$$ and take the product over all positive roots. If sage doesn't like that, you could use $$\mathrm{sum}(a2(-k*alpha),0,N)$$ for $N>>0$ to get an approximation, I guess.

Comment: @DavidHill, thank you very much.

Comment: You bet. If you get this to work, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @DavidHill, thanks. Yes, it works. I take a sufficient large $N$. But I need to remove the terms with large entries. I don't know how to do this automatically.

Comment: The codes are in the following:

    A2 = WeylCharacterRing("G2", style="coroots")
    a2 = WeightRing(A2)
    L = A2.space()
    W = L.weyl_group()
    [fw1,fw2] = [L.fundamental_weights()[i] for i in [1,2]]
    Lambda = fw2
    N=6
    rho = L.rho().coerce_to_sl()
    r1 = sum((-1)^(w.length())*a2(w.action(Lambda+rho)) for w in W)
    r2 = prod(1-a2(-alpha) for alpha in L.positive_roots())
    r3 = a2(-rho)
    e2=1
    for alpha in L.positive_roots():
        t1=0
        for i in [0..N]:
            t1=t1+a2(-i*alpha)
        e2=e2*t1
    r1*r3*e2

Comment: Nice. I'm not super confident I know how to code this, but sagemath can do limits, so if you were able to tell sage to interpret limits on the weight ring as limits in real numbers, you'd be able to automate the whole thing. Like def lim( a2(X), N, a), return lim(exp(ht(X)), N,a) or something.

Comment: @DavidHill, thanks a lot!